# Returning a specific substring from ORACLE SQL string using REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I am having a difficult time trying to return a specific section of string from a field (BSE.NOTES) using REGEXT_SUBSTR. For my query, I have a VARCHAR2 field with a specific text that I would like to return:

> Hospital Dept Name                              Case: SP12-34567                                 Authorizing Provider:  D. K, MD MSCR        Collected:           07/09/2021 12:49 PM         Ordering Location:     Hospital               Received:            07/09/2021 03:23 PM         Pathologist:           D. L., MD                                                          Specimens:   A) - Body part 1                                                                                      B) - Body part 2

From this text, I need to return the string "Case: SP**-*****" for each record. I tried using the following code, but only get NULL values:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(BSE.NOTES, '(\S|^)(Case\:\s)([0-9]\-\[0-9])', 1, 1, NULL) AS CASE_NUMB
```

I am not very versed and using regexp_substr() so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is looking for a single numeric digit either side of the `-`, and doesn't allow for the 'SP' part; it will also only match after the start of the line or a *non*-whitespace character, and your parentheses don't look right. And you haven't specified that you want a sub-pattern ([read more in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html)).

This will get the value you said you wanted:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(BSE.NOTES, '(\s|^)(Case:\sSP[0-9]+-[0-9]+)', 1, 1, null, 2) AS CASE_NUMB
from bse
```

| CASE_NUMB |
| --- |
| Case: SP12-34567 |

Or if you actually only want the second part of that you can add more sub-patterns:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(BSE.NOTES, '(\s|^)(Case:\s(SP[0-9]+-[0-9]+))', 1, 1, null, 3) AS CASE_NUMB
from bse
```

| CASE_NUMB |
| --- |
| SP12-34567 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-xvL8Pzy)

Using regular expressions to extract data from fields like this is a bit error-prone though, particularly where it's essentially free-form text that could have odd capitalisation (you can make the third argument `'i'` to help with that), spacing (maybe make the second `\s` optional, as `\s?`), typos or other oddities... And you may not need the anchor/whitespace at the start, but it might not hurt, particularly if you do go case-insensitive.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking to do. I understand and can apply this to other situations as they come up.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
WITH
bse(notes) AS (
  SELECT 'Hospital Dept Name Case: SP12-34567 Authorizing Provider: D. K,'
       ||' MD MSCR Collected: 07/09/2021 12:49 PM Ordering Location:'
       ||' Hospital Received: 07/09/2021 03:23 PM Pathologist: D. L.'
       ||', MD Specimens: A) - Body part 1 B) - Body part 2'
  FROM dual
)
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
    bse.notes    -- the string
  , 'Case:\s*SP\d\d-\d+' -- the pattern "Case:",
                         --  zero, one or more whitespace (\s*),
                         -- "SP", two digits (\d\d), a hyphen, 
                         -- one or more digits (\d+)
  ) AS extr
FROM bse;
-- out        extr       
-- out ------------------
-- out  Case: SP12-34567
```